# Multiple triggers "case"s in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

```
    var message = "hello [[xxx]] bye [[ZZZ]]"

var result, re = /\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g;
while ((result = re.exec(message)) != null) {
    switch (result[1].toLowerCase()) {

        case "xxx":
            console.log("found xxx");
            break;

        case "zzz":
            console.log("found zzz");
            break;
    }
}
```

This is an example of the code im using, currently it will output

```
found xxx
found zzz
```

Is there a way to put multiple ways to "trigger" a case? such as

```
case "xxx", "aaa", "bbb":
            console.log("found 3xletters");
            break;
```

I've tried this ^^^ but only the last thing can trigger it, so in the above case xxx and aaa wont trigger, but bbb will

Comment: ahh my bad, it is indeed :3
i did a quick search but i fear i didn't know the proper "wording" so i didn't find anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but I would not recommend it if you have very many alternatives per case. In switch statements `break` ensures that the program exists the switch statement rather than continuing on to the following cases. So, if you want to check for multiple cases, you can simply leave `break` out of all but the last one, like so.

```
...

switch (result[1].toLowerCase()) {
  case "aaa":
  case "bbb":
  case "xxx":
      console.log("found aaa, bbb, or xxx");
      break;
  case "zzz":
      console.log("found zzz");
      break;
}
```

Comment: thanks :) this is really helpful, and i would only have 2/3 triggers per case.